# Drf unique_together prevent destroy in viewset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model with unique_together constrain

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  cmp = models.ForeignKey('Titles',
       on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  env = models.CharField(max_length=32)

      class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            'cmp ',
            'env ',
        )
```

A serializer with the above fields:

```
class ExampleModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
        fields = ('id', 'cmp ', 'env')
```

And in viewsets the following destroy method:

```
 def destroy(self, request, pk):
     serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.query_params)
     serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

     instance = self.get_object()
     self.perform_destroy(instance)
```

On the line serializer.is_valid() breaks with the following error:

```
{"non_field_errors":["The fields cmp, envmust make a unique set."]}
```

Any ideas why it happens and what is the proper solution to sovle it

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to destroy something with stock DRF is to provide an unique ID (often the pk) and destroy it.
By calling the serializer without an instance, you are acting as if you want to create a new instance. This is the reason why DRF won't let you go past the validation step.

Comment: I did not understand what exactly you mean. Could you please provide an example to me

Answer (score 0):

The destroy action does not need any data, so you shouldn't provide or try to serialize the request body. It just gets the id from the URL since it's a detail endpoint, fetches the object and deletes. You may want to look at the original implementation of destroy before overriding it

Comment: Yes but what if i send extra parameters to destroy method in order to do some more process. How am i going to validate and serialize them ?

Comment: @user1292656 make a different serializer for it that only accepts and validates the fields needed when destroyed is called. The serializer you're using enforces several field to be present because it is mainly used for creating and updating. You can also pass in `partial=True` to the serializer. Or at least specify the fields that you're expecting in your post so that a solution can be suggested